# How to change the wxPython sliders value dynamically without 'lagging' the main frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, slider, wxpython

How can i change the wxPython sliders value dynamically without 'lagging' the main frame from the scripts side?

```
ex = wx.App()
Okienko(None, style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.SYSTEM_MENU, size=(400, 400))
t = threading.Thread(target=ex.MainLoop)
t.start()
i=0
while Okienko.slider1.GetValue()<30:
        sleep(1); Okienko.slider1.SetValue(i)
        i=i+1
```

That's what i tried to do, but it just makes the main frame window doesnt respond until the loop will end.

Comment: Have you tried to do the opposite - run `ex.MainLoop` in your main thread, and your `while` in a new one?

Comment: you should not update the gui in anything other than the main thread with wx ... (and I think most gui libs)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use sleep ... that will lag everything... use timers or callbacks

```
ex = wx.App()
o = Okienko(None, style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.SYSTEM_MENU, size=(400, 400))
o.Show()
t = wx.Timer()
t.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,onTimer)
def onTimer(e):
   o.slider1.SetValue(min(o.slider1.GetValue()+1,30))

ex.MainLoop()
```